# How to know the server of a website?

Tags: webserver

For example Youtube.com. How can I know the server location of youtube.com from where YouTube serve their service.

I am in Linux. I don't know `traceroute` helps or not in this case.

Comment: Are you trying to locate the physical location of the server?

Comment: Your tag doesn't help too much. If you want to see the geographical location of a public address you can use http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/

Comment: @SleepingGod I want the physical location or at least the organization name and IP

Comment: You can make an educated guess based on host names. That’s it. Youtube is hosted at many data centers all over the world.

Comment: So you want to use a website such as http://who.is then. You simply enter youtube.com in the search field to receive that Google is the owner, with some address information etc. For the ip address, a simple ping can work too.